# Difference between "slip out of" and "slip off"

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the preposition used with the verb "slip."

When you leave your bed quietly at night for a glass of water, I think you can say either of these sentences to describe your action.

> I slipped **out of** my bed and went to the kitchen.
>
> I slipped **off** my bed and went to the kitchen.

My question is, is there any difference in meaning between "slip out of" and "slip off"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lie **in** your bed, so you need to slip **out** of it.
When you would've been lying **on** your couch, you could slip **off of** it.

So you use 'slip out of' when you're **in** something, and 'slip off of' when you're **on** something.

Comment: Best not to say 'slip off of'. Also you could slip off your bed by accident, onto the floor.